# How do I make a context menu for a webview?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a context menu for a webview in my app.
I want that when the user does a long click on a link, a context menu will popup.
Something like this (the left picture, and instead of of listview I want a webview):

[image]

Thanx upfront.

Comment: See this question and the accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449098/enable-longclick-in-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wide range of options to choose from : [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html), and [PopupMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601552/android-custom-overflow-menu-without-actionbar-and-no-menubutton/10641686#10641686)

Reference : [Android custom Overflow-menu (Without actionbar and no menubutton)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601552/android-custom-overflow-menu-without-actionbar-and-no-menubutton/10641686#10641686)

Comment: I want a context menu like the one on the picture that I showed you.

Comment: You can use `ListPopupWindow`.. But since you want to show the list at point of long click you need to use `PopupWindow` as it can be used to show at location (x,y)

Comment: Use `PopupMenu` as suggested in that link.  The long clicked list item is the anchor view. The post has a sample code.

Comment: But what is the menu in the picture that i added?