# How to add actions to Overflow menu on Galaxy S3?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, galaxy

I'm facing a problem when actions intended to be shown in overflow menu in action bar are not there on Galaxy S3. As a consequence the UX is somewhat confusing - my action bar on Galaxy S3  is there to only display app logo and name but offering no extra functionality.

I'd like to have an identical UX on all devices running on Android 4.x with actions in the overflow menu. Is this possible without using third-party components such as ActionBarSherlock?

Thanls

Answer (score 2):

This is a decision made by some manufacturers that requires some "bad" solutions if you really want to do this. The overflow menu is just the "regular" old menu button that all android devices used to have. When the menu button got removed by Google in Honeycomb and ICS some manufacturers decided to keep the menu button. This has lead to great confusion about what the menu button is and does.

You should keep in mind though that the user using a S3 would expect to have a functional menu button as they would not be used to seeing a 3-dot menu. All apps using the built in menu system should appear in a way to the user that they expect. Therefor I would strongly recommend against the urge to have your app look exactly the same on all devices in this matter since it would most likely confuse users more then help them. It should be possible, to both implement the "proper" menu system and a "custom/fake" 3-dot menu if you wish however.

This post seems to have some good guidelines:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713860/1068167

Answer (score 2):

There is a quick and dirty way to fake the absence of a hardware menu button using reflection to set a field in your app's `ViewConfiguration` instance.

The following code snip can be added to your activity and called during `onCreate()`.

```
private void enableActionBarOverflow() {
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Not a clean solution as the implementation of ViewConfiguration could change at some point in the future, and since the `sHasPermanentMenuKey` field is private, there's no guarantee that the field will always be there.

However, I would only use this as a last resort if you absolutely must have an overflow menu on devices that have a menu key.

Assuming you're minimum API is 11 (Honeycomb) or greater, a better solution would be to make your own overflow menu like so:

1. Add a menu item for the overflow in your menu.xml, setting it to always show and inflate in your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       ...
       <item
           android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
           android:title="@string/settings"
           android:showAsAction="always">
       </item>
   </menu>
   ```

   ,

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
           mi.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```
2. Create a separate overflow_menu.xml resource for your choices you want in the overflow menu

   ```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <item
           android:id="@+id/overflow_action1"
           android:title="@string/overflow_action1">
       </item>
       <item
           android:id="@+id/overflow_action2"
           android:title="@string/overflow_action2">
       </item>
   </menu>
   ```
3. In your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, handle the selection of your overflow menu

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
           ...
           case R.id.action_overflow:
                   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(
                           this, findViewById(R.id.action_overflow));
                   MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
                   inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, popup.getMenu());
                   popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
                   popup.show();
                   return true;
           default:
                   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
           }
   }
   ```
4. Implement the `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener` interface in your activity to handle the clicks of the overflow items

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.overflow_action1:
           //do stuff
           return true;
       case R.id.overflow_action2:
           //do stuff
           return true;
       default:
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```